# Invalid OAuth access token for Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a simple get request via the Facebook PHP SDK, this way :

```
$rep = $fb->get('/me',$appsecret_proof);
```

and here's my configuration :

```
$config_bis = array(

'app_id' => $config['params_api'][EnvironnementExecution::if_prod() ? 'prod' : 'dev']['config']['appId'],
'app_secret' => $config['params_api'][EnvironnementExecution::id_prod() ? 'prod' : 'dev']['config']['secret'],
'default_access_token' => $config['params_api'][EnvironnementExecution::if_prod() ? 'prod' : 'dev']['access_token'],
```

);
I stock the Facebook configuration data in a `. yml` file. The issue is Facebook SDK return me that the access_token is invalid even if I checked it before via the Facebook developer interface.

```
[2015-10-22 11:26:35] Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException (pid : 11136) : Invalid OAuth access token.
```

So any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: I'd suspect that it doesn't get read (properly), and therefore the request fails. Have you tried logging the access token after it's read, and directly before the call? Also, your code doesn't show how you set the access token for your request...

Comment: i set the accces_token in the configuration array `$config_bis `. what do you mean by logging the access token ?

Comment: Yes, you LOAD it, but I don't see where you use it in `$fb->get()`

Comment: No, if you passed the access_token within the config array, you are not obliged to do it every get/post or delete query.

Comment: According to FB this is done differently: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0#login Your code doesn't show that `$config_bis` is used to configure the PHP SDK... And even if, you still didn't verify that the access token is loaded and correct

Comment: i'm getting the access token directly from here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, and not by logging

Comment: you are getting app access_token, but you need user access token,

Comment: no, it's a user access token and it dosen't work

Comment: You are aware that short-lived user access tokens are only valid for around two hours, right? So putting those into your configuration doesn’t make much sense anyway.